# MS Access - Selecting against nested user input?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to select from a table in Access from the result of another select query that has user input?

This is my initial query:

```
SELECT List FROM [Material and Finishes] WHERE Materials = [Material:];
```

I'm trying to put it into this query:

```
SELECT SubstanceName FROM [Core] WHERE Product Like '*Plastic*'
```

I'm trying to combine them in this:

```
SELECT SubstanceName
FROM [Core] 
WHERE ProductAreas > ANY 
( SELECT List FROM [Material and Finishes] WHERE Materials = [Material:])
```

However I only ever get Invalid Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery 'List'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT c.SubstanceName
FROM [Core] as c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [Material and Finishes] as mf
              WHERE mf.Materials = [Material:] AND
                    mf.Product Like '*' & c.ProductAreas & '*'
             ) ;
```